# python IP validation REGex validation for full and partial IPs

Tags: python, regex, ip

Im trying to validate the input to see if it a valid IP address(could be a partial one).

Acceptable input : 172, 172.112, 172.112.113, 172.112.113.114

Unacceptable input: 1724,172.11113 etc etc

Heres a function that I created to check it (however it validates unacceptable input like 1724 which I cant seem to fix..please help)

```
def ipcheck(ip):
    ippattern_str = '(([1-2]?[\d]{1,2}\.?){0,1}(\.[1-2]?[\d]{1,2}){0,1}(\.[1-2]?[\d]{1,2}\.){0,1}(([1-2]?[\d]{1,2}[\D\W]*)'
    ippattern = re.compile(ippattern_str)
    # ippattern is now used to call match, passing only the ip string
    global matchip
    matchip = ippattern.match(ip)
    return matchip


ip = sys.argv[1]
ipcheck(ip)

print matchip
```

I feel like maybe I need to use anchors properly? Ive tried everything to my best knowledge, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex would do the trick:

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){0,3}$
```

It ensures that the given numbers are in the correct range (0-255) and can have 1-4 parts.

You can see it in action here: http://regexr.com?2va3j

Comment: very nice website! and great reg x,as I suspected I was not using the anchors properly..thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you could avoid to use regex and let python [socket.inet_aton](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton) do the job :

```
import socket

try:
    socket.inet_aton(addr)
    # correct IP
except socket.error:
    # bad IP
```

For inet_aton, a valid IP address is something of the form :

```
       a.b.c.d
       a.b.c
       a.b
       a
```

> In all of the above forms, components of the dotted address can be
>   specified in decimal, octal (with a leading 0), or hexadecimal, with a
>   leading 0X). Addresses in any of these forms are collectively termed
>   IPV4 numbers-and-dots notation. The form that uses exactly four
>   decimal numbers is referred to as IPv4 dotted-decimal notation (or
>   sometimes: IPv4 dotted-quad notation).

[source](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet)

Comment: I need use regular expressions and secondly I dont think that sicket.inet_aton can validate partial IPs?

Comment: @A.R.B : as explained in the linked doc, inet_aton will validate partial IP. His job is to convert a valid IP into the network notation :) . For the need of regex, well, never mind ;)

Comment: ooh okay thank you so much!! i automatically assumed it wouldnt, this will be very helpful in the future :)